# need code to generate a month-month variance report

Tags: python, report

I have to generate a report of month-month stock variance report.

Here `cif_id` is a unique ID and there are a total of 18 columns: some are fetched from database and some generated from calculations. But, the problem is that for each month we need to extend our sheet with these columns.

We need to take first month as base and if the `cif_id` is not in second month: we need to carry previous months data until the `cif_id` comes and there are some variance formulas where we need to calculate the taking data from previous months data.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnqzr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mfhs.png)

```
dropdown=3
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
df1=['CIF ID','Customer Name']
file_path = 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/output.xlsx'
df1 = pd.read_excel(file_path)
query="SELECT o.[CIF ID] as 'CIF ID',o.[Customer Name] as 'Customer Name'FROM [indusind.acelive.ai_extraction].[dbo].[ocr] as o INNER JOIN [indusind.acelive.ai_queues].[dbo].[process_queue] as p ON o.case_id = p.case_id where p.queue = 'approved' and p.created_date BETWEEN '2023-10-01' AND '2023-11-30' order by p.customer_name asc;"
db=pd.read_sql_query(query, con=conn_extraction)
df1 = pd.concat([df1, db], ignore_index=True)
print(df1)
#df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_columns1)
for i in range(1,dropdown+1):
    df_columns2=['Stock Date','Total Stock','Creditors','Paid Stock/Net stock','Applicable Margin(stock)','DP on Paid Stock','Debtors Value <90 days','Applicable Margin(debtors)','DP on Debtors','Total DP','Banks Share in %','DrawingPower','MOM Variance in Stock','MoM Variance in Debtors','MoM Variance in Creditors','MoM Variance in DP']
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_columns2)
    query="SELECT o.[CIF ID] as 'CIF ID',o.[Customer Name] as 'Customer Name', o.[Stock Date] as 'Stock Date',o.[Total Stock] as 'Total Stock',o.[Creditors] as 'Creditors',o.[Stock Margin Percentage] as 'Applicable Margin(stock)', o.[Debtors Value <90 days]  as 'Debtors Value <90 days' ,o.[Debtors Margin Percentage] as 'Applicable Margin(debtors)',o.[Bank Share] as 'Banks Share in %',o.[DrawingPower] as 'DrawingPower' FROM [indusind.acelive.ai_extraction].[dbo].[ocr] as o INNER JOIN [indusind.acelive.ai_queues].[dbo].[process_queue] as p ON o.case_id = p.case_id where p.queue = 'approved' and p.created_date BETWEEN '2023-10-01' AND '2023-11-30' order by p.customer_name asc;"
    db_data = pd.read_sql_query(query, con=conn_extraction)
    df = pd.concat([df2, db_data], ignore_index=True)
    #df1 = df.copy()
    file_path = 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/output2.xlsx'
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    df['DrawingPower'] = df['DrawingPower'].fillna(0)
    df['Paid Stock/Net stock'] = df['Total Stock'] - df['Creditors']
    df['DP on Paid Stock'] = df['Paid Stock/Net stock'] * (1-(df['Applicable Margin(stock)'])/100)
    df['DP on Debtors'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: row['Debtors Value <90 days'] * (1 - (row['Applicable Margin(debtors)'] / 100))
        if row['Creditors'] > row['Total Stock']
        else row['Debtors Value <90 days'] * (1 - (row['Applicable Margin(debtors)'] / 100)),
        axis=1)
    df['Total DP'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: row['Debtors Value <90 days'] * (1 - (row['Applicable Margin(debtors)'] / 100))
        if row['Creditors'] > row['Total Stock']
        else (row['DP on Paid Stock'] + (row['Debtors Value <90 days'] * (1 - (row['Applicable Margin(debtors)'] / 100)))),
        axis=1)
    if i==1:
        df['MOM Variance in Stock'] = '0'
        df['MoM Variance in Debtors'] = '0'
        df['MoM Variance in Creditors'] = '0'
        df['MoM Variance in DP'] = '0'
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df], axis=1)
    print(new_df)
    new_file_path = 'C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/final_output2.xlsx'
    new_df.to_excel(new_file_path, index=False)
FileLink(new_file_path)
```

I tried writing code like this but I'm getting stuck at extending multiple columns based on the months and I'm failing to fetch data from multiple months.

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)